# Deriving Kinematics Equation without Calculus / First Principle

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

> How do I derive the Kinematics equation $v=v_0+at$ from the equation $x = x_0+v_0t+\frac12at^2$?

This is how I have tried :

$$x - x_0=v_0t+\frac12at^2$$

$$\Delta x= t(v_0+\frac12at)$$

$$\dfrac{\Delta x}{t}= v_0+\frac12at$$

$$v = v_0+at$$

I'm stuck with the $\frac12$. How to get rid of that ? Please Help !

Comment: Take the derivative.

Comment: Ordinarily you wouldn't be working in this direction as the displacement result is a more complicated result.

But just to answer the question, you cannot do this without differentiation. Have you been introduced to calculus?

Comment: No ! I'm a grade 11 student.... I'm not yet introduced to Calculus !

Comment: v = v_0 + at can be derived graphically, else you need calculus.

Comment: Learn Math Jax for the next time you ask a question ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is entirely possible to derive the equation without calculus, here is how:**

Firstly, you are wrong in substituting $\Delta x/t$ with $v$. The ratio $\Delta x/t$ is, the average velocity, and not the velocity at time $t$. Since this is a case of uniform acceleration, we have
$$\frac{\Delta x}{t}=v_{\text{avg}}=\dfrac{v+v_0}{2}$$
implying
$$\dfrac v2+\dfrac{v_0}{2}=v_0+\dfrac12at$$
Simplifying will give you the required equation.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Dang it , I'm a bit jealous that your answer got accepted but still +1.

Comment: @Buraian: Don't worry he still doesn't know what we did there in your solution ;) Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: Can anyone please tell me, what's going on ? What you have done ?

Comment: Did you follow my answer? @NilavNibirBora if any part of wasn't clear, then I'll check it again.

Comment: @Buraian: Should we reveal it :p

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Yaah ! Please....

Comment: @Buraian Yes I went through that.... for me it's somehow hard to understand....still trying !

Comment: @Nilav: he actually used calculus without showing it explicitly. The answer uses the roots of calculus, so it's possibly hard to comprehend as you're not familiar with calculus.

Comment: That was exactly the idea xD

Answer (score 2):

Hmm how about this:

$$x(t+\Delta t)=x_0 + v_0( t + \Delta t)+ \frac12a(t+ \Delta t)^2$$

We know that at each and every point the velocity is different since there is an acceleration, but let's take a small time interval $(t,t+\Delta t)$, then change in position for this interval of time is given as::

$$ x(t + \Delta t) - x(t) = v_0 \Delta t + \frac12 a( 2t \Delta t + \Delta t^2)$$

Now, if to find velocity we divide by the time gap:

$$ v(t) = \frac{x( t+ \Delta t) - x(t)}{\Delta t} = v_0 + \frac12 a( 2t+ \Delta t)$$

But remember, each point has a different velocity due to acceleration, so to get the best idea for rate of change of position for the motion at a point, let us take the time gap to be really small then we find that all terms of $\Delta t$ on RHS die off:
$$ v(t) = v_0 + at$$

And that's it.

Comment: Psst: No one tell him  what we are doing here ;)

Answer (score 0):

To derive it the way you want you would need some basic calculus (derivatives), but the equation $v = v_{0} + at$ can be understood without that. The definition of acceleration ($a$) is change in velocity ($v$) per second. This equation only works when the acceleration is constant so the change in velocity over a period of ($t$) seconds is $at$ (literally change per second times number of seconds). Then it is clear that the equation says "final velocity = initial velocity + change in velocity".

If you want to get the basics of calculus, here is a great series on it:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr

Comment: Thanks You ! I have that intuition. But still wanted to derive that mathematically. I had thought it would be possible without Calculus. Thanks for the Playlist !

Answer (score 0):

$$ x = v_0t + ½at²$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v_0+\frac{2}{2}at$$ ~ Differentiate respect to time.
$$v=v_0+at$$

You can learn calculus from [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7HbxnIjedJvnxGd6FNeBVKzPAWHnXZAr). I like these tutorial.

Comment: I think I had solved the problem without calculus also. I will see later.

Comment: How ? I think you're talking about the graphical method.